# Spring REST API - direct activation of API(No Webserver)

Tags: java, spring, rest

I have a Java application that gets information on a general purpose channel.

I cannot listen on another port, and the application does not have(or implements) a webserver.

I want to activate some of the application's functionalities via REST API.

I already have the requested URI and parameters(of a single client request), but they are not in an HTTPRequest class.

How can I directly call the Spring REST API, using the data I have?

To illustrate what I want to do:

In `myREST.java`:

```
class myREST {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/foos", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody
    public List<Foo> getAllFoos {
        return foos;
    }
}
```

and in another file:

```
JSONObject restAPICaller(String uri, JSONObject params) {
    JSONObject response = springRestAPI.call(uri, "GET", params);
    return response;
}
```

where for instance, my uri is `/foos/` , and params is `{}` (will have content for other examples)

Comment: Why do you have to go through JSON and use an uri? Isn't `List<Foo> foos = new myREST(). getAllFoos();` good enough? Please explain

Comment: @giorgiga - not good for me. The uri and params are received on a "web like" interface, and I want to use the spring REST  capabilities( parse the uri and activate the correct function). This is done mostly because I share my functionality between multiple applications, some have normal webserver accessibility, and some not

Answer (score 0):

> How can I directly call the Spring REST API, using the data I have?

You *cannot* use an API via an HTTP client without an HTTP server.

I guess you can either:

1. Embed a server in your app and have it listen on some network port (you can bind to 127.0.0.1, so that the service is not accessible from other machines).
2. Directly call into the REST API classes (eg: `new myREST(). getAllFoos()`)
3. Call into the business logic layer your API classes call into (iff you properly structured your code there)